# Magento sales_order_grid + join concatenated results from other query

Tags: database, collection, sales-order, query, group

We have some queries / extensions adding columns to the `sales_order_grid` as a 1:N relation. Normally 1:1 relations work fine. 1:N relation need a `group by` statement on `increment_id` and use `group_concat` or `SUM` or some other group statement to 'merge' the 1:N results.

Our problem occurs when more than 1 extension/query uses the group concat. Then we are beginning to see duplicate results in some columns. Seaming using `group_concat` can best be used only once.

**My question is**: How can you best join a 1:N relation in a concatenated form to the original `sales_order_grid` without using `group_concat`.

I can think of nesting the concat subquery in the select statement. Or creating a view where the query results are stored and hence can be joined 1:1 instead of 1:N. Or the data can be stored in it's own method and joined like that - only often there is no 1 other table but the join is based om another query all together involving multiple tables.

```
Main table                 Query
sales_order_grid incr_id   select incr_id, group_concat(new_column) from T1 and T2, group by incr_id
```

As is the Query above is incorporated in the Magento select statement making it too complex. But how can we only add the 'result' of this subquery - so in essence the concat has already occured before adding it to the sales_order_grid select statement.

(I hope this is clear)

How can one remove the group_concat and group by in this query. And add it as a subquery in the SELECT using Magento and SQL methods/collections: how do we do the below "Magento style"

ORIGINAL

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse_tbl.`warehouse_id` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `warehouse_ids`, GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse_tbl.`qty` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `warehouse_qtys` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `safemage_multiinventory_warehouse_order_item` AS `warehouse_tbl` ON warehouse_tbl.order_id = main_table.entity_id AND warehouse_tbl.qty <> 0 GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`
```

POSSIBLE SOLUTION

```
select *
FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
left join 
(select warehouse_tbl.order_id as unique_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse_tbl.`qty` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `warehouse_qtys`,
GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse_tbl.`warehouse_id` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `warehouse_ids`
from `safemage_multiinventory_warehouse_order_item` AS `warehouse_tbl` 
where warehouse_tbl.qty <> 0 GROUP BY warehouse_tbl.order_id) as wh 
on wh.unique_id = main_table.entity_id
```

Comment: can you provide the full query. i will check

Comment: see added mysql ... after statement actually works .... only I dont know how to "make it like this" in PHP and Magento using collection methods